# Is there a Typescript compiler option to prevent a subclass method from removing the optional nature of a parameter?

Tags: typescript

I recently discovered a fun little bug that looks rougly like this:

```
class Base {
  public thing(attribute: Attr, player?: Player) { ... }
}

class Subclass extends Base {
  public thing(attribute: Attr, player: Player) { player.something(); }
}
```

... somewhere this happens:

```
doThing(base: Base) {
  base.thing(attribute /* no second parameter */)
}
```

which throws an exception because there's no `player` to invoke `something`.

This seems like the kind of bug I'd like the compiler to report on. Is there a `tsc` option I'm missing?